# Avoiding SSL errors in Xcode's Preview window

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ssl-certificate

I'm pretty new to Swift/SwiftUI programming so I used a URLImage package from https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image-demo in which I want to display images from my local computer. The images would have the following path: https://myserver.local/path/img1.jpg
The easiest way to make me self-signed cert work was to create a CA Root Cert and install it on simulator within Xcode and enable Full Trust. It's taken me half a day to configure the certs correctly, but in the end my code works when I start debugging in the simulator.

```
struct SListItem: View {

    var solImage: String {
        get {
            return "https://myserver.local/path/image1.jpg"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            URLImage(
                url: URL(string: solImage)!,
                options: URLImageOptions(
                    cachePolicy: .returnCacheElseLoad(cacheDelay: 0.0, downloadDelay: 0.25),
                    load: [.loadImmediately, .cancelOnDisappear],
                    maxPixelSize: CGSize(width: 3000, height: 3000)
                ),
                empty: {
                    Text("Nothing here")            // This view is displayed before download starts
                },
                 inProgress: { progress -> Text in  // Display progress
                        return Text("Loading...")
                },
                 failure: { error, retry in         // Display error and retry button
                    VStack {
                        Text(error.localizedDescription)
                        Button("Retry", action: retry)
                    }
                },
                content: { $0.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) }
            ).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            
            Text("Test123")
        }
    }
}
```

But during preview/live preview this results in this error:
**An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.**

However all of the following are true:

- I can access the image without SSL issue in Chrome, Safari on my macOS host (CA Cert is installed in System keychain and is trusted for all users; the web server has SSL cert signed by my CA Cert)
- I can access the image without SSL error from Safari on the simulator (after CA Cert was installed and fully trusted)
- As mentioned above I can access without SSL error the image when I run app in the debug mode in the simulator from Xcode.
- If I choose an image on a website which has a third-party signed SSL cert then the image is displayed correctly in both simulator and preview pane.

This leads to me to believe that Xcode's Preview pane uses some other repository where I would need to put my CA Cert to make it work. If such an option exists at all.

I'm using iPhone 11 Pro Max as the preview scheme/simulator, iOS deployment target 14.3 is selected.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Next should help https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/15720

Comment: I was afraid someone would suggest that ;) I've seen articles about using NSAppTransportSecurity and playing with URLSession, but I for the moment I dismissed them since my knowledge of Apple/Swift environment is just too limited (I've written C/C++ on Windows, but never Objective-C on Mac) - I just had hoped there must be a simpler approach. But if there isn't then I will have to do a lot of reading. Thanks.